# "Unjoin" cloned SLES VM without "net ads leave"

Tags: linux, active-directory

we set up two SLES 12 VM's over the last weeks.
Both VM's are joined to our Active Directory.

Now those VM's have been cloned to a different ESXi Host for testing purpose. (Every change should be tested on the clone before it will be implemented on the production system).

The cloned VM's have been started without any network access and I already changed IP's and Hostnames.

Now I want to remove the clones from the AD on client side so I can rejoin them. I can't use "net ads leave" (tells me it can't reach the AD but can't run it with connected network, this would also remove the original vm from the AD).

Is there any way to clean up configurations so that the system thinks it was never joined the AD and I can do a fresh join? (Only found information about doing this on windows, but not on Linux systems)

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did some tests and the following worked:

1. Booting the cloned VM's without network access
2. Changing the hostnames and reboot to apply changes
3. Connect the network and assign an IP
4. Run net ads join to join the new clone (with it's new hostname) to the AD